# Display the field value based on the value selected from the drop down in django forms

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I am a newbie!! I have a task to populate a field value based on the option selected from the drop down menu.

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import MainPage
import datetime
from datetime import date

techlist = (
    ('DateOfDrive', 'DateOfDrive'),
    ('NameOfDrive', 'NameOfDrive'),
    ('Status', 'Status'),
    ('Marks_Scored', 'Marks_Scored'),
    ('First_Round_Interviewer_Name', 'First_Round_Interviewer_Name'),
    ('Second_Round_Interviewer_Name', 'Second_Round_Interviewer_Name'),
    ('Third_Round_Interviewer_Name', 'Third_Round_Interviewer_Name'),
    ('Management_Round_Interviewer_Name', 'Management_Round_Interviewer_Name'),
    ('HR_Round_Interviewer_Name', 'HR_Round_Interviewer_Name')
)


class analysisForm(forms.Form):

    GroupBy = forms.ChoiceField(choices=techlist)
    where = forms.CharField()
    datefrom = forms.DateField(initial="2019-01-01")
    dateto = forms.DateField(initial=date.today())
```

views.py

```
class analysis(FormView):
    template_name = 'analysis.html'
# View for the analysis page

    def get(self, request):
        form = analysisForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = analysisForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            groupbyf = form.cleaned_data['GroupBy']     # Getting the groupby otpion from the user
            wheref = form.cleaned_data['where']  # Getting the search element from the user
            datetof = form.cleaned_data['dateto']       # Getting the end date from the user
            datefromf = form.cleaned_data['datefrom']   # Getting the from date from the user

            # Loading the excel to data frame
            query = str(Summary.objects.all().query)
            df_view_summary = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)
            print(df_view_summary)

            # Extracting the month number from the complete date
            df_view_summary['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df_view_summary['DateOfDrive']).month
```

analysis.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action=""  method="post">

        {% csrf_token %}

        <table>
            {{ form.as_p }}
        </table>

          <input type="submit">
        </form>
            # Loading the excel to data frame
            query = str(Summary.objects.all().query)
            df_view_summary = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)
            print(df_view_summary)

            # Extracting the month number from the complete date
            df_view_summary['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df_view_summary['DateOfDrive']).month

</body>
</html>
```

What changes should I do now to populate the where field in django based on the value selected from drop down groupby field in the form. As soon as a value is selected in the drop down populate the where field with values which would be sent by views.
How to do this without ajax/Javascript.

Comment: are you looking to populate ( class analysisForm(forms.Form): ) and save it to database using form??

Comment: yes I would select a value from the groupby dropdown in the field and based on its value I want to populate the where field in the same form without submit so that I can fill rest of fields in the form and then use it in views.py

Comment: You are most welcome to give suggestion but could you please specify any link or change my code based on your answer so that i can proceed in that direction.

Comment: Sorry but it didnt answer my question. Anyways thanks for the help.